# How to use trunc() function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I'm a little confused about using `trunc()` function in postgresql.

As far as I know, if I want to trunc date, I need to use the `date_trunc()` function in posgresql.

It looks like this: `select date_trunc('month',now())`.

But I found that there's a `trunc()` function in `pg_catalog`. If I use it like ths: `select trunc(now(),'MM')`. I will get the same result. This usage is similar to oracle.

I'm not sure if this is a built-in functions in postgre 13.3.

I've done some researchs on the internet, but I cannot see any description about these 2900+ functions in `pg_catalog`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: My v13 has 5 trunc functions in pg_catalog, but none of them take a timestamptz as their first argument.  Maybe you installed some compatibility extension that added it.  (But I wouldn't think it would add it to pg_catalog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is no built-in PostgreSQL function. Also, it references the library from the [orafce](https://github.com/orafce/orafce) extension that defines a function like that.

To verify that, connect to PostgreSQL with `psql` and run `\dx` to list the extensions. `orafce` should be among them. To see the objects provided by the extension, run `\dx+ orafce`. To see the schema where orafce is installed, use `\dx orafce`.

The image you added to the question suggests that the function is in `pg_catalog`, but the extension is installed in `public`. Since it is forbidden to create functions in `pg_catalog`, somebody must have modified the PostgreSQL catalogs to make that happen. I'd say that your database is messed up. You can try to `DROP EXTENSION orafce`, followed by `CREATE EXTENSION orafce SCHEMA public`, perhaps that can repair the damage.

Comment: I checked `\dx+ orafce` result. It seemed to be from 'orafce' extension, but why would it be added to pg_catalog?

Comment: It cannot be in `pg_catalog`. Most likely it is in `public`. `\dx` will tell you the schema of the extension.

Comment: I check the result by `\dx`. It seems to belong to orafce. But why is it in `pg_catalog`? You can see the screenshot in my updated question.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: This the version infomation that I got by using `select version();`  PostgreSQL 13.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1), 64-bit

Comment: The remaining alternative is that somebody messed up the catalogs. What do you get for `\dx orafce`?

Comment: Yes. I see the `trunc(timestamp with time zone,text)` function by `\dx+ orafce`.

Comment: That's not what I was asking.

Comment: I got `List of installed extensions
Name  | Version | Schema |Description
orafce | 3.15    | public | Functions and operators that emulate a subset of functions and packages from the Oracle RDBMS
(1 row)` by `\dx orafce`

Comment: Thanks. So the extension is installed in `public`. Do you see that function in `\df public.trunc`? Anyway, if there is `pg_catalog.trunc` function that references orafce, then somebody messed up your PostgreSQL catalogs.

Comment: `Do you see that function in \df public.trunc? ` No. Anyway, thank you for your patient answer.